# Warning in vue dev tool

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, dom-events

I have a project and in project i have 3 file :

1 . index.html

2 . main.js

3 . Vue.js (Vue library)

My index.html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body{
            padding-top: 40px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="root" class="container">
        <coupon @applied="OnCouponApplied"></coupon>
        <h1 v-show="couponApplied">applied</h1>
    </div>
    <script src="../index/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And my main.js :

```
    window.Event=new Vue();

Vue.component('coupon',{
    name:'coupon',
    template:'<input placeholder="enter you`r code" @blur="OnCouponApplied">',
    methods:{
        OnCouponApplied(){
            Event.$emit('applied');
        }
    }
});
new Vue({
    el:'#root',
    data:{
        couponApplied:false
    },
    created(){
        Event.$on('applied',()=>alert('handle!'));
    }
});
```

But I have **two warnings**:

*Warnings* :

> vue.js:597 [Vue warn]: Property or method "OnCouponApplied" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.
>
> (found in <Root>)
>
> vue.js:597 [Vue warn]: Invalid handler for event "applied": got undefined
>
> found in
>
> ---> <Coupon>
> <Root>

It work correctly and now I want too know is there any solution to these warnings?

Comment: In the body, `<coupon @applied="OnCouponApplied"></coupon>` is using `OnCouponApplied` which doesn't exist in the root Vue instance

Comment: thank a lot for help.

Answer (score 2):

in the `main.js` we don't have `OnCouponApplied` in Vue instance.

so i delete `OnCouponApplied` in `index.html`.

And fix a `main.js` to have better View(Don't use $emit and $on) :

```
window.Event=new class{
    constructor(){
        this.vue=new Vue();
    }
    fire(event,data=null){
        this.vue.$emit(event,data);
    }
    listen(event,callback){
        this.vue.$on(event,callback);
    }
};

Vue.component('coupon',{
    name:'coupon',
    template:'<input placeholder="enter you`r code" @blur="OnCouponApplied">',
    methods:{
        OnCouponApplied(){
            Event.fire('applied');
        }
    }
});
new Vue({
    el:'#root',
    created(){
        Event.listen('applied',()=>alert('handle!'));
    }
});
```

Comment: It's not a good idea to redefine `window.Event`. I would choose a different name.

Comment: if you have another idea please post for me in answer mode.thank.

Comment: In fact, you could wrap your code in a [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) (at least) so you wouldn't don't need globals.

Comment: register  your event bus like `Vue.use(function (_Vue) {
  _Vue.prototype.$myBus = new class{
    constructor(){
        this.vue=new Vue();
    }
    fire(event,data=null){
        this.vue.$emit(event,data);
    }
    listen(event,callback){
        this.vue.$on(event,callback);
    }
}
}, {})`, uses it like `this.$myBus.fire('applied')`